# Prevent scrolling to top when re-initializing Morris gragh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, morris.js

I have a Morris Graph [here](http://umairayub.ezyro.com/test.html).

I have to re-populate/initialize with new data upon click of img/span.

These span/img

```
<span class="a" onclick="changeGraph('all', this)"><img src="http://umairayub.ezyro.com/fetchPG_files/hour.png"> All</span>
<span class="a" onclick="changeGraph('hour', this)"><img src="http://umairayub.ezyro.com/fetchPG_files/hour.png"> Hours</span>
<span class="a b" onclick="changeGraph('weeks', this)"><img src="http://umairayub.ezyro.com/fetchPG_files/hour.png"> Weeks</span>
```

This is JS code.

```
function changeGraph(type, obj) {
 // some calculation here.
 createPGhistoryGraph(finalArray) 
}

function createPGhistoryGraph(pg_data) {
    $("#pg_scrape_history").html('');
    if (typeof Morris !== "undefined" && $("#pg_history_data").html() != '[]') {
        var x = new Morris.Area({
            element: 'pg_scrape_history',
            resize: true,
            data: pg_data,
            xkey: 'date',
            ykeys: ['price'],
            labels: ['Price'],
            lineColors: ['#a0d0e0', '#3c8dbc'],
            hideHover: 'auto',
            hoverCallback: function (index, options, content, row) {
                return "<div class='morris-hover-row-label'>" + row.date + "</div><div class='morris-hover-point' style='color: #a0d0e0'><a href='" + row.link + "' target='_blank'>Price:" + row.price + "</a></div>";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can see `var x = new Morris.Area({` is the part initializing the graph.

**ISSUE** is that when I click on one of button the whole page is scrolled up,

[image]

I have no idea how to prevent this scroll-up with simple JS or at Morris plugin's source code level. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you deleting and recreating the graph every time you receive new data?

You can do something like this, to update your chart without having to delete the DOM elements:

```
var chart = Morris.Area({ ... });

var asyncCallback = function(newData) {
  chart.setData(newData); // this will redraw the chart
};
```

[Source: http://morrisjs.github.io/](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html)

[Example using the setData api](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/blob/master/examples/updating.html)

Comment: Simply amazing!